# why are these two sets equal?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm in the middle of a proof of a certain lemma

and it is stated with no explanations that :

$$ \{ \omega \in \Omega \;|\; \sup f_n(\omega) > x \} = \cup_{n\geq1} \{ \omega \in \Omega \;|\; f_n(\omega) > x \}$$

$(f_n)_{n\geq1}$ represents a sequences of functions that maps from $\Omega$ onto $\mathbb{R} \cup\{+\infty , -\infty\}$

$x$ is an arbitrary real number

I tried thinking about it but I'm stuck something seems wrong but I can't figure out what.

perhaps the way the sets are written ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sup_n f_n(\omega)>x,$ that means there exists some $m$ such that $f_m(\omega)>x.$ For the supremum of a set (in this case, $\{f_n(\omega)\}_n$) to be strictly greater than a number, it suffices for any element of the set to be greater.

On the other hand, if $\omega\in\bigcup_n\{\omega\colon f_n(\omega)>x\},$ that means, again, there is some $m$ such that $f_m(\omega)>x.$ That's what it means to be in a union; you're in one of the sets.

Think about how it would be different if instead the predicate in the set were $f_n(\omega) < x.$ Then on the right-hand side, we would need to be taking intersections instead of unions. Do you see why?